# Python: Calculate metrics from list of APIs

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, metrics

I have a array of data that looks something like this:

```
#API name, min, max, average
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '336.0', '336.0']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '339.0', '337.5']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '339.0', '338.0']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '341.0', '338.75']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '353.0', '341.6']
['findProductById', '841.0', '841.0', '841.0']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '920.0', '438.0']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '944.0', '510.29']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '952.0', '565.5']
['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '975.0', '611.0']
['findProductsByCategory', '113.0', '113.0', '113.0']
['findProductById', '161.0', '841.0', '501.0']
['findProductByPartNumber', '255.0', '975.0', '575.4']
```

What I want to do is, for each individual API, generate something like this:

```
API, Min, Max, Average, 90th Percentile
findProductByPartNumber, 278.69, 770.25, 458.69, 565.5
findProductById, 373.0, 841.0, 571.67, 501.0
findProductsByCategory, 112.33, 187.17, 154.46, 167.75
```

This is the aggregated results of each API above. What would be the best way to do this in Python?

EDIT:

I have the following Java code what does what I want. Java is my best language and I am trying to learn Python and I'm not familiar with the data structures.

```
double[] apiValues = new double[3];
apiValues[0] = Double.valueOf(min);
apiValues[1] = Double.valueOf(max);
apiValues[2] = Double.valueOf(average);
parseAPILogs.registerAPI(name, apiValues);
...
...
private static void registerAPI(String apiName, double[] apiValues) {
    if(!averagePerAPI.containsKey(apiName)) {
        APIData data = new APIData();
        data.addValues(apiValues);
        averagePerAPI.put(apiName, data);
    } else {
        averagePerAPI.get(apiName).addValues(apiValues);
}
}
```

The APIData Java class is a little big to past here, but you can see the idea I was going with.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I answered, but you should provide code you have tried in the future to show effort on your part.

Comment: I have edited to include the Java code I have that does this but I am trying to learn Python and nothing I have come up with has really done the trick. I'm not too familiar with Python data structures so was hoping for some sample code to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
def aggregate(stats):
    aggregated = {}
    for stat in stats:
        key = stat.pop(0)
        stat = map(float, stat)
        if key not in aggregated:
            vals = {"avg": []}
            aggregated[key] = vals
        aggregated[key]['min'] = min(stat[0], aggregated[key].setdefault('min', stat[0]))
        aggregated[key]['max'] = max(stat[1], aggregated[key].setdefault('max', stat[1]))
        aggregated[key]['avg'].append(stat[2])
    return aggregated

def print_stats(aggregated):
    for k, v in aggregated.items():
        print k, 
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if k1 == 'avg':
                print "%s: %s" % (k1, sum(v1) / len(v1)),
            else:
                print "%s: %s" % (k1, v1),
        print

 stats = [
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '336.0', '336.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '339.0', '337.5'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '339.0', '338.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '341.0', '338.75'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '353.0', '341.6'],
        ['findProductById', '841.0', '841.0', '841.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '920.0', '438.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '944.0', '510.29'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '952.0', '565.5'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '975.0', '611.0'],
        ['findProductsByCategory', '113.0', '113.0', '113.0'],
        ['findProductById', '161.0', '841.0', '501.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '255.0', '975.0', '575.4']
        ]   

print_stats(aggregate(stats))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
findProductsByCategory max: 113.0 avg: 113.0 min: 113.0
findProductById max: 841.0 avg: 671.0 min: 161.0
findProductByPartNumber max: 975.0 avg: 439.204 min: 255.0
```

As far as 90th percentile, it isn't possible to calculate without the individual samples unless you just use .9 * avg.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have hard coded stats to the multidimensional array as above but I am getting this error when trying execute. Any ideas?
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parselogs.py", line 109, in <module>
    aggregateStats = aggregate(stats)
  File "./parselogs.py", line 23, in aggregate
    aggregated[key]['min'] = min(stat[0], aggregated[key].setdefault('min', stat[0]))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: You are likely overwriting the builtin `min` function by doing something like `min = <something>`.  When you do this, you are replacing the reference to the built-in function and that is a no-no.

Comment: Thank you - that was it. Both the solutions here work great but I will accept yours because it was the first. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [ ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '336.0', '336.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '339.0', '337.5'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '339.0', '338.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '341.0', '338.75'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '353.0', '341.6'],
        ['findProductById', '841.0', '841.0', '841.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '920.0', '438.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '944.0', '510.29'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '952.0', '565.5'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '336.0', '975.0', '611.0'],
        ['findProductsByCategory', '113.0', '113.0', '113.0'],
        ['findProductById', '161.0', '841.0', '501.0'],
        ['findProductByPartNumber', '255.0', '975.0', '575.4']]

d = list(set([item[0] for item in arr]))
d = dict(zip(d, [[0, 0, 0, 0] for k in range(len(d))]))

for k in arr:
    d[k[0]][0] = min(k[1], d[k[0]][0]) if k[1] is 0 else k[1]
    d[k[0]][1] = max(k[2], d[k[0]][1])
    d[k[0]][2] = sum(map(lambda x: float(x[3]) if x[0] is k[0] else 0, [api for api in arr])) / len(filter(lambda x: x is k[0], [api[0] for api in arr]))

for k in d.keys():
    print "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(k, d[k][0], d[k][1], d[k][2], d[k][3])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm getting an error similar to the other solution. Any ideas? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parselogs.py", line 103, in <module>
    d[k[0]][1] = max(k[2], d[k[0]][1])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable